# Active Directory group managed by

Tags: batch-file, cmd, active-directory

I was looking a way to bulk updated users in managed by tab in AD group, and I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using code like this

```
dsquery group -name group_name |dsmod group 
        -chmbr "CN=John,OU=Europe,DC=domain,DC=com" "CN=Will,OU=Europe,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

And I thought this will replace John with Will but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using powershell, you can do it, even if its bulk- its just that you're AD should have ADWS service running, and your powershell is at version 2 and up(to be able to use AD commandlets : import-module active directory) which is not the case on my end. We're using Win2k8 enterprise and its prretty much not configured as yet so I am also looking for DSMOD group/

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit wordy, so I apologize up front...

(This assumes the needed permissions in AD and the AD command line tools installed)

Here's how I would do this on the command line:

dsquery user -samid SamAccountName | dsget user -memberof

This would query the user and then show which security group(s) the user was associated with.

To add a given user to a security group:

dsquery user -samid SamAccountName | dsmod group "Distinguished Name of Security Group" -addmbr

To add MULTIPLE users to a SINGLE security group, I would use a simple text file with the users' SamAccountName (1 on each line) and loop through like this:

For /F %i in (Full Path to text file with users) do dsquery user -samid %i | dsmod group "Distinguished Name of Security Group" -addmbr

(Should work, not tested)

Me, I'd normally just grab the users from any given container, right-click and choose 'Add to a group..." and, having the name of the security group in the clipboard, just paste the name of the group the users would be added to.

PowerShell would be completely different, but there are many ways to do this same task.

Looking at your original question, I'm not sure if you're looking to update your users' security group membership OR you want to update a given object's 'Managed By' attribute.  I went with the former.  If it's not the case, you may want to clarify.